# Twilio audio issue in Chrome (macOS Sierra)

Tags: google-chrome, audio, twilio

I cannot get Audio to work using Twilio in Chrome Version 60.0.3112.78 (Official Build) (64-bit) (macOS Sierra).

I am using https://networktest.twilio.com/ to test audio playback and I can't hear a thing.

Same test works perfectly fine in Firefox. This rules out speaker or microphone issues on hardware level.

In Chrome, I gave permission to microphone and when i tested it using custom web app I wrote using Twilio's SDK, people on the other side can hear my voice, but I can't hear anything from other side, not even automated voice messages. Again, the same custom app works just fine in Firefox. How should i troubleshoot this ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. Uninstalled Chrome, Removed all data and re-downloaded new version and installed it. Audio is working as expected now.